# Get output of Python command using Popen

Tags: python, bash, shell

I'm trying to execute a shell command from within Python (2.6.4) to evaluate a simple formula before passing it as an argument to another program. My input is something simple like this:

> $[2*2]

I want to evaluate that expression and get the result from within my Python script so I can use it later. Currently, I'm doing this (where `token` is `$[2*2]`):

```
token = subprocess.Popen(["echo", token], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()
```

I expect the output to be `4`, but instead it's just giving me back my original token (`$[2*2]`). Obviously when I jump to the shell and run this command by hand (`echo $[2*2]`), I get `4` as expected.

Is there something special about how Python executes this command that I'm missing?

Comment: This probably is a duplicate. I did some searching, but I didn't find this answer quickly. Feel free to close it.

Comment: This is actually a __FAQ__ and should be on the tag wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `echo $[2*2]` in your shell, the **shell** evaluates `$[2*2]` and passes the results of that evaluation to the `echo` command. In your Python code, you are passing the `$[2*2]` to echo directly and hence, it is returning just that.

You can invoke a shell to evaluate your command using `shell=True` in `subprocess.Popen`:

```
token = subprocess.Popen(["echo " + token], 
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0].strip()
```

Comment: Even that may fail if `/bin/sh` is not Bash, but that's another point :)

Comment: very true, but F.J provided a specific answer to that as well.

Answer (score 2):

`subprocess.Popen` will automatically escape any arguments passed in so that the command is run with those literal strings, or in other words the command that is run is equivalent to `echo '$[2*2]'`.  There are two ways to get around this:

- Use `shell=True`:

  ```
  >>> import subprocess
  >>> token = '$[2*2]'
  >>> subprocess.Popen("echo " + token, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0].strip()
  '4'
  ```
- Run bash or another shell as your command:

  ```
  >>> subprocess.Popen(["bash", "-c", "echo " + token], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()
  '4'
  ```